# Magento 2: how to change default Country option on checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout

I'm using magento 2.0.7 and I'm trying to change the default Country on the checkout page, from United States to United Kingdom.
I have already set from *STORES* > *CONFIGURATION* > *SALES* > *SHIPPING METHODS*, the method option to specific country, and only selected UK, but it still doesn't work, probably because I have to edit any file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change Sales/Tax/Default Tax Destination Calculation

**for more information on how this logic works:**

vars config:

- defaultCountryId
- defaultRegionId
- defaultPostcode

```
vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/TaxConfigProvider.php
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/new-customer-address.js
```

Comment: This is not the right answer.

Comment: When one country select default as Sales/Tax/Default Tax Destination Calculation its work for me. Thanks

Comment: Work perfect :)

Comment: not works, change but no success

Answer (score 3):

In the **Admin** area, *Stores* > *Settings* > *Configuration* > *General* > *General* > *Country Options* > *Default Country*, select desired country from the list.

Then clean '*Configuration*' and '*Page Cache*' caches (*System* > *Tools* > *Cache Management*).

And finally you have to clear cookies from the browser.