# Why cart page shows the message "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time"?

Tags: magento2, shipping, shopping-cart

In the Estimate Shipping and Tax section, there is a message

> Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time

[image: Magento2 no quotes are available]

How to restore form like normally and get rid of this message?

Answer (score 3):

Seem we are missing the Shipping Methods. We need to enable one shipping methods for testing: **STORES > Configuration > SALES > Shipping Methods**. We can enable Free Shipping.

[image]

Comment: still no changes.

Comment: Clear Magento Cache and Local Storage.

Comment: yeah, i already do that.

Comment: You are on Checkout or Cart page?

Comment: i am on cart page

Comment: You can take a screen shot and update your question.

Answer (score 2):

When you enter city and zipcode for shipping address, values need to be accurate. If you try with some dummy values, it will not work.

[image: Sample shipping address for Australia]

Comment: thax its usefull

Comment: Magento way (best option) : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/165041/165

Answer (score 2):

We encountered the same problem -- Our issue was that the service, UPS or USPS updated their api rules where only **HTTPS** was required.  Changing our Gateway URL to **HTTPS** instead of HTTP fixed the problem.
This is set in Settings>>Sales>>Shipping Methods.

**Other things to keep in mind:**

- Ensure the product type is 'SIMPLE TYPE', not 'VIRTUAL'. You can't ship a virtual product... See the DB table `**catalog_product_entity** for more details

  - Ensure the checkbox for Weight is checked 'THIS ITEM HAS WEIGHT'. A actual numeric rate was not required per our testing.
  - Allow UPS Checked

Comment: Thanks. HTTPS issue resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This means you have configured shipping for your store but no shipping condition passed and back end does not have shipping quotes for customer.

This can be due to several reasons like shipping configuration, or the addresses can not be covered by shipping you had configured.

Logic to handle this message and condition you had inquired is present in `<magento-website-root>\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\shipping_method\available.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was because I was using UPS as my only shipping method and I had my origin in China.

UPS couldn't calculate any shipping prices when shipped from China, so my only solution was to switch the origin to a location in the US.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Table Rates.

[image]

After exporting CSV File in Step #2. Open the CSV file in Text editor (Notepad++ and etc.)

[image]

Then After putting the details **Import** the CSV File.

Lastly, make sure the products has **Weight** and Clear the Cache.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the customer does not have an address or is invited so they have calculated shipping rates to 0 (except shipping methods as flat rate).

To solve this error there are two solutions:

1. configure shipping method with flat rate or do not need country, province and zip code
2. **https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121904/165**

**In some checkout modules you can configure from the module itself**

Answer (score 0):

MAKE SURE ALL YOUR PRODUCTS HAVE WEIGHT!!! JUST FIXED FEDEX BY ADDING WEIGHT.

Comment: Please add some more content.