# Magento 2: Shipping methods are not displayed while checkout process when cart quantity is 1

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have integrated custom theme, when i add product in the cart and go to checkout page the shipping methods are not displayed and sometimes its shows shipping method error

> sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time

but when i change the product quantity or I add more than 1 product in cart the shipping methods works fine.

Is there any solution for this type of issue?

This is the screen shot of shipping configuration setting
[image]

Comment: what error showing?

Comment: now check console what types of error are display.

Comment: please check the updated ques

Comment: which shipping method enable in your configuration setting check.

Comment: flat rate and aramex

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149586/magento-2-show-message-sorry-no-quotes-are-available-for-this-order-at-this-ti/149589

Comment: sorry, that was not my ques

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67756/discussion-between-mandar-parbate-and-ravindrasinh-zala).

Comment: Try disabling any recently installed extensions, and see if the error still appear or not

Comment: thnx, Yes it was another plugin issue. @MGento

Comment: @MandarParbate - I am facing the similar issue. can you please tell me, which plugin was causing the issue. As I am facing the issue particularly with Bss- multi store view pricing.